# How are words with "ps" or "pt" pronounced?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, pronunciación, consonantes, griego

Here are a few examples:

> psicología
>
> ptosis
>
> Ptolomeo

Interestingly "[sicología](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sicolog%C3%ADa)" is also found in the RAE but most of the time I've seen it written as "[psicología](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=psicolog%C3%ADa)".

- How are they pronounced?
- What are the roots of these "ps" and "pt" words?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are usually pronounced as if the "p" didn't exist. It's because these words come from the Greek. The RAE in *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* explains in [its article about *p*](https://www.rae.es/dpd/p):

- **For words starting with Ps-**

> 3. El grupo consonántico **ps**, resultado de la transcripción de la letra griega **psi**, aparece en posición inicial de palabra en numerosas voces cultas formadas sobre raíces o palabras griegas que comienzan por esa letra (psyché ‘alma’, pseudo- ‘falso’, psittakós ‘papagayo’, etc.). En todos los casos se admite en la escritura la reducción del grupo ps- a s-, grafía que refleja mejor la pronunciación normal de las palabras que contienen este grupo inicial, en las que **la p- no suele articularse**: *sicología*, *sicosis*, *siquiatra*, *sitacismo*, *seudoprofeta*, etc. No obstante, el uso culto sigue prefiriendo las grafías con ps-: *psicología*, *psicosis*, *psiquiatra*, *psitacismo*, *pseudoprofeta*, etc., salvo en las palabras *seudónimo* y *seudópodo*, que se escriben normalmente sin *p-*.

- **For words starting with Pt-**

> 4. En algunas voces cultas de origen griego, o formadas sobre raíces griegas, se mantiene en posición inicial de palabra el grupo consonántico pt, especialmente en voces científico-técnicas: *pteridofito*, *pterodáctilo*, *ptosis*, etc. No obstante, lo más habitual ha sido que las palabras procedentes de voces o raíces con grupo pt- inicial en griego se hayan incorporado al español sin p-: *tisana*, *tialina*, *tialismo*, *Tolomeo*, *tomaína*, etc.

- **For pt inside a word** the "p" is pronounced weakly and even sometimes not pronounced in "séptimo" or "septiembre".

> 5. La pronunciación de la **p se relaja considerablemente** en el grupo pt situado en interior de palabra, pero solo es corriente su pérdida en ***séptimo*** y ***septiembre***, que se pronuncian a menudo en el habla espontánea, al menos en España, [sétimo] y [setiémbre]; por ello se admiten también las grafías sétimo y setiembre, aunque en el uso culto se siguen prefiriendo decididamente las grafías con -pt-. En todos los demás casos (abrupto, aceptar, concepto, corrupto, Egipto, óptimo, etc.), la reducción de -pt- a -t- debe evitarse tanto en la grafía como en la pronunciación. Son excepción los participios de los verbos pertenecientes a la familia de escribir, que por influencia de escrito (forma usual hoy frente a la anticuada escripto), se escriben preferiblemente sin -p-: adscrito, descrito, inscrito, suscrito, transcrito, etc.; no obstante, en algunas zonas de América, especialmente en la Argentina y el Uruguay, son de uso normal las formas con -pt-.